# bash perl "and" operator

Tags: perl, regex

with a output:

```
apple text1
peach text2
banana text3
melon text4
```

For delete rows that begin with "apple" or "banana" i put:

```
perl -pe 's/^apple.*\n|^banana.*\n//g'
```

And output is correct:

```
peach text2
melon text4
```

But I want delete also an eventual "papaya" or "mango" for example. For achieve this I apply the De Morgan law:

```
perl -pe 's/^(?!peach).*\n&^(?!melon).*\n//g'
```

But nothing is deleted because while "|" stands for "or", "&" does not work.
What symbol stands for "and" in bash perl command?

Comment: It would be more idiomatic to use something like `perl -ne 'print unless /^(apple|banana)/'`

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? Do you want to delete anything that does NOT match "peach" or "melon"? In that case, use `perl -ne 'print if /^(peach|melon)/'` - this will print **only** lines that start with "peach" or "melon". Your second example (with "&") is a misunderstanding of what regular expressions are - they are just very advanced patterns that are matched to text. You can't treat them as logical expressions. Read more about Perl regular expressions here: https://perldoc.pl/perlre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate the two matching expressions like this:

```
perl -pe 's/^(?!peach)(?!melon).*\n//g'
```

or you can use the "or" operator like this:

```
perl -pe 's/^(?!(peach|melon)).*\n//g'
```

Comment: GOOD, GOOD! The second one is the best solution.